# intersection of Galois extension of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

In Dummit and Foote's book,there is a Proposition

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be Galois extensions of a field $F$.Then the intersection $K_1\cap K_2$ is Galois over $F$.
The proof is as following:

Suppose $p(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ with a root $a$ in $K_1\cap K_2$.Since $a\in K_1$ and $K_1/F$ is Galois,all the roots of $p(x)$ lie in $K_1$.Similarly,all the roots lie in $K_2$,hence all the roots of $p(x)$ lie in $K_1\cap K_2$.It follows easily that $K_1\cap K_2$ is Galois as in Theorem 13.

I feel a little confused about the last step,By Pro 13($K/F$ is Galois iff K is the spltting field of some separable polynomial over $F$),we need to show find a separable polynomial.But $p(x)$ mentioned above is irreducible,if the $Char(F)\neq 0$,irreducible polynomial may not be separable.

Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is already given $\;K_i\;$ are Galois over $\;F\;$ , so they **must** be already separable extensions of $\;F\;$ ...

Comment: How to show that $p(x)$ is separable?

Comment: if it has a root $\;a\in K_1\cap K_2\;$ it **must** be separable as all the elements in $\;K_1, K_2\;$ are separable, which meants their minimal polynomials are separable.

Comment: @DonAntonio Why must $K_1 \cap K_2$ be the splitting field of $p(x)$ though? I get that $p(x)$ is separable and splits completely over $K_1 \cap K_2$, but why cannot $p(x)$ split completely over some proper subfield of $K_1 \cap K_2$?

Comment: @Frito That wasn't the point of my comment but merely to stress the fact that $\;p\;$ must be separable. Now for any $\;a\in K_a\cap K_2\;$ let $\;p_a(x)\in F[x]\;$ be its minimal polynomial. By what is proved in the questions, each $\;p_a\;$ splits completely over $\;K_1\cap K_2\;$ and thus $\;K_1\cap K_2\;$ is the splitting field of $\;\{p_a\;|\;a\in K_1\cap K_2\}\subset F[x]\;$ , which finally proves the intersection is Galois.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hmm so now $K_1 \cap K_2$ is the splitting field of a collection of polynomials? I don't recall that definition in Dummit, something like: ``If $F$ is a field and $S \subset F[x]$ is a collection of polynomials, we say an extension $K$ of $F$ is a *splitting field* of $S$ over $F$ if every polynomial in $S$ splits completely in $K$, and for any proper subfield of $K$, there is some polynomial in $S$ which does not split completely in $K$.'' ?

Comment: @frito_mosquito That's exactly the definition of *normal extension* in D&F, immediately after theorem 25 in chapter 13: splitting field *of a collection of polynomials*, and it also appears in V, theorem 3.3. of Lang's Algebra, for example.